# Why does my php code not update when i run it

Tags: php

So i have this html form that connects to a php script on the same page. the way it should work is that you enter a form (selcect). the output goes trough a elseif to check all the posible outputs. But this doenst work, the vars dont change at all.

The thing I tried are setting the vars to null at the beginning and restarting my XAMPP enviroment, both didnt work.

html:

```
  <form method="POST">
    <select name="sLand">
      <option value="NED">Nederland</option>
      <option value="BEL">België</option>
      <option value="LUX">Luxemburg</option>
      <option value="GER">Duitsland</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Bestel">
  </form>
```

php:

```
$sLand = "sLand";
$sLand = $_POST['sLand'];


if($sLand = "NED")
  $sOutput = ("test");
elseif($sLand = "BEL")
  $sOutput = ("test 2");
elseif($sLand = "LUX")
  $sOutput = ("test 3");
elseif($sLand = "GER")
  $sOutput = ("test 4");

echo($sLand);
echo($sOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two `=` signs to compare values:

```
if ($sLand == "NED")
```

instead of

```
if ($sLand = "NED")
```

and so on